# Aptana 3 code assist for ExtJS 3.4

Tags: extjs, aptana, extjs3, code-assist

I am using Aptana 3.07 and I want code assist for ExtJS 3.4.

I have tried the SPKET solution, but I cannot seem to be able to take full advantage of it. The following example demonstrates this.

**Example**

```
Line 1: var win = new Ext.Window();
Line 2: win.show();
```

In the above example, the first line offers code assist. However, when, at the second one, I type "win.", no proposals are available.

I have included "Ext-all.js" during the configuration of the SPKET editor.

Is there anything else that I should do or is there any other way of achieving ExtJS code assistance in Aptana?

Thank you.

Comment: try NetBeans 7. It has a great JS editor.

Comment: Thank you, @neil. I've already tried NetBeans and its js support is great. However, I'd like to make Aptana work because it has some features I'd like to use for my current project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a post of mine with a tutorial of how to make code assist for ExtJS in Aptana!
[link here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?112540-Aptana-Code-Assist-for-Sencha-Touch&p=635681&viewfull=1#post635681)

Edit: The post is very old now and programs have evolved. Here you can find a [link](http://tutorials-fourtytwo.blogspot.co.at/2012/08/tutorial-sencha-touch-extjs-code.html) to an updated source of how to add code assist for Sencha products in Aptana and/or Eclipse.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is indeed the solution to my problem. One minor change. The proposed repository: http://www.spket.com/update/ in step 2 is deprecated... http://www.agpad.com/update should be used, instead.